# How download track with Soundcloud API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

i want to download track from Soundcloud using Soundcloud SDK v3

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
```

i retrive tracks from website normaly using this script (javascript)

```
SC.get('/tracks',{
        original_format: 'mp3',
        sharing: 'public',
        streamable: true,
        downloadable: true,
        state: 'finished',
        track_type: 'original'
    }).then(function(tracks) {

    var html = '';
    $.each(tracks, function(index, track){
        html += previewTrack(track);
    });

    $('#tracks-wrapper').append(html).hide().fadeIn();
    $('.icon-refresh','#refresh-btn').removeClass('fa-spin');
});
```

my tracks playing fine, but i dont know how download them from soundcloud via API.
For example i get this response from website when i play track using SDK.

```
attachments_uri: "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/259412502/attachments"
download_count: 0
download_url: "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/259412502/download"
downloadable: true
```

finally my problem is how i can download this track ..
if i use this `download_url` on browser, its not working

Please help me..

sorry about my english..

Comment: If I enter that download_url in my browser it says:{"errors":[{"error_message":"401 - Unauthorized"}]} - Is that track public?

Comment: you need a api key to get there

Comment: sorry... i have api key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your client id, otherwise you won't be authorized to download it. https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/259412502/download?client_id=CLIENT_ID

Comment: For some audios in some browsers, file without extension gets download. due to that file can not be played after download. Can you explain why this kind of behavior happening ?