# PHP / Web Hosting: How to add an mp3 download button and how does that relate to web hosting

Tags: php, audio, download, web-hosting

I want to list out a bunch of mp3s and allow users to download them. I understand how I can download my own files with PHP, but I don't get how this will translate to other users downloading them when the website is live. Here are some specific questions.

-My understanding of web hosting is you pay for them to hold all the files you need for your website to run. Is this correct? If you have 100+ mp3s would that be pretty expensive?

-My backup is just have soundcloud embeds (they are my own songs) and redirect visitors to there. Any ideas for an alternative to this? It'd be cool if they could download from my site without having to make a soundcloud account.

-Is there a way to to make a download button that just pulls the file from soundcloud?

Thanks.

Comment: Web hosting packages usually come with several GB of storage space, and traffic should be no problem either, for a 100+ mp3 files. And if you don't need anything advanced like download counters or access restrictions - then you can simply put them somewhere on your server and just set _links_ to them, so that users can download them.

Comment: You might be able to do something like curl on your server and use your server a proxy to soundcloud. https://gist.github.com/lmammino/4353399 Then as far as a button which would download right away, if it's pointing at your server, you can use a link and give it the HTML `download` attribute, provided there's no cross-domain involved, it and will download upon click of the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download your own files via PHP from your own PC it will still work the same way when your web page is hosted on a server. When you program in PHP and do your tests, your PC acts as a server to run PHP (as it is a server side programming language). So essentially when you download mp3s while testing the program on your own pc, your pc will act as the client and the host at the same time.

When somebody hosts your website they do it on a server, a server is basically just a computer. It usually has a lot of space for files, so it should not make a difference in cost wether you have 1 mp3 file on there or 100.

As for downloading directly from soundcloud I am not sure if that will work, but this older stackoverflow post might help you. [How download track with Soundcloud API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668430/how-download-track-with-soundcloud-api)

Comment: Soundcloud api sound really cool! That sounds like a much better solution than tunneling with curl on the server like I was thinking would need to be done.